# width of the width and height not working

Tags: html, css

hi i am just trying to change width and height of .content class. but its  giving me like 100px of width and 100% of height even if i don't mention. 
i have tried removing float but stil not working.what is the reason?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>

      body{margin:0}
      #navbar{
              width:100%;
              background-color:black;
              height:50px;
              padding: 0 150px 0 150px;
              position:relitive;
       }
       #logo{height:60px;
             width:90px;
            }
        #container{
              background-color:#E6E6E6;
              width:78%;
              margin: auto;
              height:1000px;
              text-align:center;
        }
        #navTable{ 
                   color:white;
                   position:absolute;
                   top:10px;
                   left:300px;  
                   font-size:1.5em;
                 }
        #navTable td{padding:0 10px 0 10px;
                     border-right:1px solid white;
                     }
        #container div{width:32%;
                       height:100%;
                       border:1px solid black;
                       float:left;
                      }         
        .content{                           /*this is not working[enter 
                 background-color:yellow;
          } 
  </style>

</head>
<body>
        <div id='navbar'>
          <img id='logo' src="http://i.cdn.cnn.com/cnn/.e/img/3.0/global/misc/cnn-logo.png"/>
          <table id='navTable'>
                <tr>   <td>Home</td> <td>News</td> <td>Money</td> <td>Entertainment</td> <td>Travel</td>   </tr>
          </table>

        </div>

        <div id='container'>

             <div id='leftDiv'>
                <div class='content'>hhhh</div>      <!--this-->
             </div>

             <div id='middleDiv'></div>
             <div id='rightDiv'></div>
        </div>      
</body>
</html>
```

output:
  it only gives me like 100px wide div here .

Comment: The reason is that you have style for #container div and it's affecting the result. CSS priority is why defining it in .container class will be ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the selector `#container div` it means every `div` element inside, including `div` inside `div`. You should use `#container > div` if you mean to apply it just to direct children.

Note you said you did not defined `height:100%`, but actually you do! Your problem is that your `#container div` selector applies also to `#container div div.content` element.

You can use `!important` or be more specific in your CSS selectors:

```
#container > div { ... }
#container > div > .content { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

As @RLaaa said: "The reason is that you have style for `#container` div and it's affecting the result".

If you want to keep all styles that you have already wrote, you just need to use `!important` in your case for `.content` such properties, for example (random values):

```
.content {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 500px !important;
  height: 200px !important;
}
```

You can change this to any values you like. Here is the snippet:

```css
      body{margin:0}
      #navbar{
              width:100%;
              background-color:black;
              height:50px;
              padding: 0 150px 0 150px;
              position:relitive;
       }
       #logo{height:60px;
             width:90px;
            }
        #container{
              background-color:#E6E6E6;
              width:78%;
              margin: auto;
              height:1000px;
              text-align:center;
        }
        #navTable{ 
                   color:white;
                   position:absolute;
                   top:10px;
                   left:300px;  
                   font-size:1.5em;
                 }
        #navTable td{padding:0 10px 0 10px;
                     border-right:1px solid white;
                     }
        #container div{width:32%;
                       height:100%;
                       border:1px solid black;
                       float:left;
                      }         
        .content {
                 background-color:yellow;
                 width: 500px !important;
                 height: 200px !important;
          }
```

```html
        <div id='navbar'>
          <img id='logo' src="http://i.cdn.cnn.com/cnn/.e/img/3.0/global/misc/cnn-logo.png"/>
          <table id='navTable'>
                <tr>   <td>Home</td> <td>News</td> <td>Money</td> <td>Entertainment</td> <td>Travel</td>   </tr>
          </table>

        </div>

        <div id='container'>

             <div id='leftDiv'>
                <div class='content'>hhhh</div>      <!--this-->
             </div>

             <div id='middleDiv'></div>
             <div id='rightDiv'></div>
        </div>
```